# Tweak NLTK sentence tokenizer reserve sentence in bracket

Tags: nltk

I have a sentence where I don't want it split inside brackets, any idea?

Examples:

> Today is Monday. [Money can buy this and this. But it can't buy love.]

current output:

> Today is Monday.
>
> [Money can buy this and this.
>
> But it can't buy love.]

expected output:

> Today is Monday.
>
> [Money can by this and this. But it can't buy love.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some preprocessing of your input data. use split() function to split at opening and closing brackets. In this way, you can index the elements, being "normal" sentences and sentences enclosed in brackets alternatingly. then you can decide upon this which shall be splitted and which not. Then rejoin the elements and restore brackets if you need them.